# How to print 2D arrays in a table with key name(just one time) and all it's values php?

Tags: php, html, arrays

```
Array
(

 [1JANATAMF] = Array
     (
         [0] = 4.10
         [1] = 5.10
         [2] = 6.10
         [3] = 7.10
         [4] = 8.10
         [5] = 5
         [6] = 0.02
         [7] = 5413
     )

 [1STPRIMFMF] = Array
     (
         [0] = 12.90
         [1] = 1.90
         [2] = 16.90
         [3] = 11.90
         [4] = 14.90
         [5] = 24
         [6] = 04
         [7] = 10
     )
```

I have this kind of arrays. Now I want to print then in a table with the key name of the main arrays (once) on the table row with its all values.
Table I Want is like:

```
1JANATAMF    4.10   5.10  6.10   7.10   8.10   5   0.02  5413
1STPRIMFMF   12.90  1.90  16.90  11.90  14.90  24  04    10
```

My Code is this which prints all keys together and some values at the end.

```
foreach ($c as $keys =>$values)
         echo $keys . " ";`enter code here`
     foreach ($values as $key=>$data)
         echo " " . $data . "<br>";
```

Comment: it's working just perfect thanks a lot man,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use simple `foreach()`:

```
foreach($array as $key=>$value){?>
<tr>
    <td><?php echo $key;?></td>
    <?php foreach($value as $val){?>
        <td><?php echo $val;?></td>
    <?php } ?>
</tr>
<?php }?>
```

Sample output: https://3v4l.org/gFhO7

Answer (score 0):

One way is You can use array_values() and foreach() like this :

```
$arrVals = array_values($1JANATAMF)
foreach($arrVals as $value){
    // Use Html To Create Table and add $value to columns
}
```

Comment: this array has 329 keys, need a dynamic method for this